# Location test of the ratios of random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, with not much progress. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Suppose I have $X_1, .., X_5, Y_1, ..., Y_5, X'_1, ..., X'_5, Y'_1, ..., Y'_5$, i.e., I have 4 groups of 5 random variables each. The r.v.s in each group are i.i.d. and follow the unknown distributions $X, Y, X', Y'$, respectively.

I would like to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \mathbb{E}\dfrac{X}{Y} = \mathbb{E}\dfrac{X'}{Y'}$. I've been fairly stuck on how to do this. If it's any easier, I'm also fine with testing the null hypothesis $H'_0: \dfrac{\mathbb{E}X}{\mathbb{E}Y} = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}X'}{\mathbb{E}Y'}$.

Here's the progress I've made so far:

1. I think that non-parametric tests don't give me enough power here, due to the small number of samples, so I'm trying to go with a parametric approach.
2. Based on domain-specific knowledge, I know that each of $X, Y, X', Y'$ can be modeled as a negative binomial distribution (I'm looking at count data). I've already been able to fit MLEs of the mean and shape parameters for each distribution.
3. I'm pretty sure that I want to use some simulation-based method to solve this problem, but I haven't figured out what is the right quantity to simulate.
4. If it helps, I have about 30,000 sets of these 20 observations, of which I believe ~80% would not reject the null hypothesis. I tried to construct an empirical null distribution (using the ratio of ratios as the test statistic) from these 80%, but given the need for FDR correction, my p-value threshold becomes very low and this empirical test has not given me enough power.

Any ideas, pointers, etc. would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do your 30,000 sets have possibly different $\mathbb{E}X$ etc., or are they the same?

Comment: When $Y$ follows *any* negative binomial distribution, $\mathbb{E}(X/Y)$ is undefined because there is a positive probability of obtaining a fraction with a zero denominator. Thus the null hypothesis makes no sense.

Comment: @jbowman: The $\mathbb{E}X$ are fairly different. Of course, there are some that are close...

Comment: @whuber Yes, I should've mentioned that. I realize that in theory, $Pr(Y = 0) > 0$, but in practice this isn't a major issue both because $Pr(Y=0)$ is small, and because I'm willing to assume a zero-truncated NB distribution. I'd be happy with looking at $\mathbb{E}(X/(Y+1))$.

Comment: So I've actually found that based on simulation, the ratio of two NB distributions fits a log-normal distribution pretty well. So I've tried using Welch's t test on the log-ratios (i.e., $log(X_i/mean(Y))$ vs $log(X'_i/mean(Y'))$. Does that seem valid?